# Unable to confirm the user registration via AWS SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

The AWS documentation for JS SDK says:

> Force Change Password
>   The user account is confirmed and the user can sign in using a temporary password, but on first sign-in, the user must change his or her password to a new value before doing anything else.

User accounts that are created by an administrator or developer start in this state.

But if for such a user I try to call `forgotPassword` method of SDK, it errors saying something like: `Password cannot be reset in the current state`.

SO how can I complete the registration of a user (created by admin in IAM) from my website. Which is the SDK method that should be called ?

Comment: `change_password(**kwargs)
Changes the password of the IAM user who is calling this operation. The AWS account root user password is not affected by this operation.

To change the password for a different user, see UpdateLoginProfile . For more information about modifying passwords, see Managing Passwords in the IAM User Guide .`

Comment: From the AWS docs: change_password method apparently works only for the authenticated users not for the first time users.

Comment: Ah, yes...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40287012/how-to-change-user-status-force-change-password

Comment: I have been through this thread. So does this mean, there is no way to approve the registration of a user without cli. If the admin creates a user only he can confirm the user. Seems weird. Isn't it ?

Comment: yes, it seems that way. no direct way at least to authenticate the user. Although I can see feature request raised to aws for this. I will try to get more info.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up an Auto Verify Lambda Trigger on the Pre Sign Up Trigger will allow for the user to be a confirmed state, which may get you to the point you are looking for?

Lambda -> Node.js

Give it an appropriate Title

Place the below value in the code:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    // Confirm the user
    event.response.autoConfirmUser = true;

    // Set the email as verified if it is in the request
    if (event.request.userAttributes.hasOwnProperty("email")) {
        event.response.autoVerifyEmail = true;
    }

    // Return to Amazon Cognito
    callback(null, event);
};
```

Save

Then Select newly created trigger in General Settings -> Triggers -> Pre sign-up

Answer (score 0):

**We can do this,**

- I previously answered mongodb to aws cogniton migration question.
- Go through step by step. I explained that the user's created by admin need to change the password(forgot password) but there's still another way to do it. Checkout my answer,

**Some content from my answer,**

AdminCreateUser:

- Create a new user profile by using the AWS Management Console or by calling the AdminCreateUser API. Specify the temporary password or allow Amazon Cognito to automatically generate one.
- Specify whether provided email addresses and phone numbers are marked as verified for new users. Specify custom SMS and email invitation messages for new users via the AWS Management Console.
- Specify whether invitation messages are sent via SMS, email, or both.

After successful user creation,

- authenticate user using same user credentials Use: SDK calls InitiateAuth(Username, USER_SRP_AUTH)
- After success of initateAuth, amazon Cognito returns the PASSWORD_VERIFIER challenge with Salt & Secret block.
- Use RespondToAuthChallenge(Username, , PASSWORD_VERIFIER)
- Amazon Cognito returns the NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED challenge along with the current and required attributes.
- The user is prompted and enters a new password and any missing values for required attributes.
- Call RespondToAuthChallenge(Username, , ).
- After successful password change user can be able to login using same credentials which admin created.

Refer: [Unable to confirm the user registration via aws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55116599/can-users-be-migrated-from-my-mongodb-database-to-aws-cognito-user-pool/55117084#55117084)